# How to make a div positioned at the left, be at the bottom in mobile mode?

Tags: html, css

```css
.preview img {
   width: 113px;height: 113px;margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 preview">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/794566134611804164/93DBmxZk_400x400.jpg">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/794566134611804164/93DBmxZk_400x400.jpg">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/794566134611804164/93DBmxZk_400x400.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9">
 <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/794566134611804164/93DBmxZk_400x400.jpg" >
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a div for the preview images of the product at the left and another div for the main preview. What I want is the preview images at the left will be at the bottom of the main preview in mobile mode. Can you advice me what to do or some css tricks?

Comment: Do you have more css than that? how are you positioning the elements to the left?

Comment: i positioned the mini pics using col-md. and i have another div at the right for the product description which i didnt show

Comment: you could try using css grid or flexbox to position your elements instead which would allow you to change the positioning on certain breakpoints or you could just change the col-md-3 to col-lg-12 and that will use the full width of the column which will make them stack

Comment: thanks, but im wondering i tried making the mini images' class: preview as display flex , but it's on the top,

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `flex-direction` attribute depending on the media queries to achieve this.

It has been a while since I used bootstrap, but here is a vanilla css example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>links</div>
  <div>rechts</div>
</div>
```